# Why do my pasted images looked cropped in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: image, crop, paste, libreoffice, writer

I'm writing an academic paper in Writer, and wherever I paste an image into it, the image will look cropped, like this (notice the top section):
[image]

However, if I paste the same image in any other writer document, it will look just fine:

[image]

I have to mention that I initially imported my paper from Microsoft Word, but that was a long time ago, and I've been working on it quite a lot since then. If I cross-check the image properties from the two documents, they look exactly the same...

What might be the issue?

Comment: It's possible the original conversion from Word might have left some kind of document corruption that over time has developed into this image-mangling behavior.  It might be worth trying to open the document with OpenOffice to see if the behavior is the same as LibreOffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by just copying everything from this document into a new document. This way, I lost the original styles, but I got rid of the image issue as well. I then changed my styles manually to make my document look like before.

Answer (score 4):

I have this problem too, and as you say it was fixed by copying the content into a new document. However, that's a real pain since the images, if they're anchored to the page, aren't picked up by **Select All** and have to be copied individually.

I was determined to discover the root of the problem, and since LO documents are actually zip archives containing XML files, I unzipped both versions of the document into separate directories and diffed them. I found that the default style for graphical objects, called *Graphics*, has some paragraph properties associated with it that you can't edit from the modify-style GUI. I fixed it by manually editing the document's `styles.xml` and removing the `fo:margin-top` attribute from this style, and then reinserting `styles.xml` back into the `.odt` using the `zip` command.

The complete process is as follows:

1. `unzip MyDocument.odt -d MyDocument`
2. Edit `MyDocument/styles.xml` in a text editor
3. Search for `<style:default-style style:family="graphic">`
4. Look for `style:paragraph-properties` shortly after it.
5. Remove `fo:margin-top="0.265cm"` shortly after that
6. `zip MyDocument.odt -d MyDocument/styles.xml`

I subsequently discovered that you *can* change these properties temporarily as follows:

1. Select the image
2. Use **Format** > **Spacing** > **Decrease Paragraph Spacing** repeatedly until the menu item grays out.

The white band will now have disappeared. However, if you save and reload the document, the problem reappears. Also, if you open **Styles and Formatting** and use **Update Style** the rest of the images in the document don't change.

Clearly a bug, and I guess I should report it, but that's more work than I have time for right now. I've already wasted more than enough time as it is! You've already solved your problem, but hopefully this will help someone else one day.